# How does PROTOTYPE scope work in SPRING with a method call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prototype

Does "listenercontainer(i)" method call create a new bean everytime?

OR

it is just a regular method?

If it is a regular method call, then how can I create a new bean in containers method?

```
   @Configuration
    public class JMSConfig {
        private int value=5;

        @Bean(initMethod="start",destroyMethod="stop")
        @Scope("prototype")
        public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(int i) {
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
            ....//container properties
            return container;
        }

        @Bean
        public Set<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> containers() {
            Set<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> containers = new HashSet<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>();
            for(int i=0;i<value;i++){
                DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = listenerContainer(i);
                containers.add(container);
            }
            return containers;
        }
}
```

Can I autowire Springapplication context and use that to create a new bean?

My main method code

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(PncPublisherApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype scope in Spring(5.0) works as following :

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you request it through a getBean() method call on the container.

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)